# problem in inserting data into table in 24-073110-XX format ????

Tags: c#, ado.net

I need help insering an id into the database in ASP.net mvc (C#). Here theid is the primary key and it should be in the format `24-073110-XX`, where XX represents a numeric value which should be incremented by 1.

How should I insert the id in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob said - don't store the whole big identifier in your table - just store the part that changes - the consecutive number.

If you really need that whole identifier in your table, e.g. for displaying it, you could use a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
  ADD DisplayID AS '24-073110-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) PERSISTED
```

This way, your INT IDENTITY will be used as an INT and always contains the numerical value, and it will be automatically incremented by SQL Server.

Your `DisplayID` field will then contain values like:

```
ID  DisplayID
 1  24-073110-01
 2  24-073110-02

12  24-073110-12
13  24-073110-03

21  24-073110-21
```

Since it's a persisted field, it's now part of your table, and you can query on it, and even put an index on it to make queries faster:

```
SELECT (fields) FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE DisplayID = '24-073110-59'
```

**Update:**

- I would definitely **not** use `DisplayID` as your primary key - that's what the `ID IDENTITY` column is great for
- to create an index on `DisplayID` is no different than creating an index on any other column in your table, really:

  ```
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SomeIndex ON dbo.MyTable(DisplayID)
  ```

Comment: thanks it work well.....
Is it possible to use 'DisplayID' as primary key??????
how to perform index in above query....

Answer (score 1):

If the `24-073110-` part of the data is always going to be the same, there's little to no point in storing it in the database. Given that you've said that the `XX` component is a numeric value that increments by one, I'd suggest having your table created similarly to this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
  MyTableId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  /*
      Other columns go here
  */
)
```

This way, you can let the database worry about inserting unique automatically incrementing values for your primary key.